# How do I create a shadowed box in with HTML/CSS like Apple's website so nicely has?

Tags: html, css, shadowbox

Apple's website has a lot of visually appealing elements and sometimes the fledgling web developer may look at certain elements and wonder just how to reproduce that look. So I pose the question (and will provide the answer):

How does Apple do the drop shadowbox with rounded corners?

Comment: have you tried using the stylesheet inspector in the Developer Tools to find out?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's done by just designing the box in photoshop and exporting it with the shadow already on it. However, there are new CSS3 techniques that allow you to do it thought code:

[See this website](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)

Comment: Yea I've used the Photoshop technique before, but it's not very flexible if you want your site to be dynamic and your shadowboxes to be able to dynamically change size and retain the effect. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned I have the answer:

the css for the effect is as follows

```
.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-color: #E5E5E5 #DBDBDB #D2D2D2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 210px;
    width: 320px;
}
```

[Check out a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheEternalAbyss/dNUUp/2/) of this code to see it in action.

Hope this helps anyone looking for a quick and easy shadowbox.

~TheEternalAbyss

Comment: I think they’re actually using a bit more CSS than that, seeing as the code you’ve posted doesn’t work in Safari.

Comment: No, you need `-webkit-` not `-moz-` for safari

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chrome’s Inspector](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/elements.html) or [Firefox’s Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) can show you the HTML and CSS they’re using.

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
-webkit-box-shadow
```

for webkit engine (safari, chrome) based browsers